# Is it possible to pass a struct member name as an argument in a function?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, arguments, inline

I'm writing heuristics to solve a grid but and I end up having the same code block repeated 4 times in the function body with each time very minor differences, so i was advised to write an inline function to make it better looking.

my grid is a struct with a member size and lines are represented by another struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  int size;
  binline *lines;
} grid_t;
```

and

```
typedef struct
{
  uint64_t ones;
  uint64_t zeros;
} gridline;
```

ones (resp zeros) being a binary integer which bits represent the position of ones (resp zeros) in the grid, I chose to represent lines this way because they can either be 1 or 0 or empty.

So what I have now is a function which entry looks like
`static inline bool subheuristic(grid_t *grid, ..., ..., char c)`
and in the body I test if 'c' is a ONE or a ZERO to then apply the corresponding heuristic.

Issue is that it doesnt really reduce the code size...
I was wondering if it was possible to take as argument something "some" and then in the body instantly use it to access for example `grid->gridline.some` which would in this case really reduce the code size.

Comment: C doesn't have the [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming) needed to do something like that.

Comment: It seems like you have made a more complex data structure than needed. As I understand your description, the lines member of grid_t contains ones and zeros while the ones member of gridline contains the index values of the ones and the zeros member contains the index values of the zeros. It appears that grid_t and gridline are simply two representations of the same information.

Comment: Could you provide more source code, simplified if possible? *There are* ways to write generic code in C even with some forms of reflection.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways of achieving the desired functionality in C.

One cannot pass member's name to a function *but* one can pass the member's  offset within the struct. The offset can be obtained from a standard `offsetof` macro defined in `stddef.h`.

```
#include <stddef.h>

uint64_t get_grid_bits(const gridline *gl, size_t offset) {
  return *(uint64_t*)( (char*)gl + offset );
}

...

gridline gl = { .ones = 13, .zeros = 42 };
get_grid_bits(&gl, offsetof(gridline, ones)); // return 13
get_grid_bits(&gl, offsetof(gridline, zeros)); // return 42
```

Note, that the behavior is fully defined by the C standard because any part of any object can be accessed by pointer arithmetic on `char*` type.

[Works](https://godbolt.org/z/7xvj1474j) like a charm.

Comment: removing the const keyword, would it be possible to modify the value of ones/zeros fields in the functions ? assuming i offsets and grid pointer as an argument

Comment: @BriacBruneauSunkkie, yes, assuming that the original object is declared without `const` qualifier. `gridline gl = { ... }` is fine, but for `const gridline gl = { ... }` the Undefined Behavior would be invoked.

Comment: Works like a charm only if you use offsetof. But it does not prevent passing any other argument. Then it will invoke UB. to make it 100% UB free you need to add asserst or runtime checks

Comment: @0___________. one could use a macro `#define get_grid_bits(gl,member) get_grid_bits(gl, offsetof(gridline, member))`

Comment: ? https://godbolt.org/z/njKq4Kb8r

Comment: @0___________, I don't get what is the purpose of your godbolt. The issue can **trivially** solved by moving define **after** definition of `get_grid_bits` function or by wrapping function's name in parenthesis. See [1](https://godbolt.org/z/jqa4njeo9).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in C language, but I would use an inline function which will be nicely optimized to the very simple operation when you pass the constant expressions as `bit` and `type`

```
typedef struct
{
  uint64_t data[2];
} gridline;

typedef enum {zeroes, ones} type; 

static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) uint64_t get_grid_bits(const gridline * restrict gl, const type t) 
{
  return gl -> data[t];
}

static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void set_grid_bit(gridline * restrict gl, const type t, int bit) 
{
    gl -> data[t] |= 1ULL << bit;
}

static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void reset_grid_bit(gridline * restrict gl, const type t, int bit) 
{
    gl -> data[t] &= ~(1ULL << bit);
}

static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int get_grid_bit(const gridline * restrict gl, const type t, int bit) 
{
    return !!(gl -> data[t] & (1ULL << bit));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dzMM7vfnb